# Does IPhone development device require an AT&T plan

Tags: iphone

Just trying to getting things straight before signing up in the development program and paying my $99.  I have an older iPhone that we'd like to use for development so I don't have to do anything to my current iPhone.  Does the device used for iPhone development require an AT&T plan of any kind.  We need data access, but the wifi would suffice for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be OK with just with WiFi if you are not wanting to use the packet data or telephony in your app.

You can develop apps for the iPhone with just an iPod Touch.

Comment: Just for clarification, can you tell me what you mean by packet data?  Is that a specific thing when using the cell antenna of the cell phone?  Just want to make sure that isn't something I would need.

Comment: Packet data is the conventional way of referring to data travelling over 3G or other airwaves.

Comment: I've been developing apps on a touch, i just cant access the camera or telephony data.